# Django many to many serializer invert nested json representation

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, many-to-many

in Django have a many to many relatonship where I  use selected_related to fetch the related tables data. However, the related tables data is nested inside each record, I'd like to inverse the relationship, is this possible without a custom serializer?

to go from :

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "item": " Sub item",
    "parent_items": {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "Parent Item Number 1",
 }
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "item": " Sub item 2",
    "parent_items": {
        "id": 2,
        "description": "Parent Item Number 2",
 }
]
```

to invert the parent relationship:

```
[
  {
    "parent_items": ""Parent Item Number 1",
    "id": 1,   
    "item": {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "Sub Item 1",
      }, 
     { 
     "item": {
        "id": 2,
        "description": "Sub Item 2 ",
  },

},
{  
    "parent_items": " Parent Item Number 2",
    "id": 2,

    "item": {
        "id": 1,
        "description": "SubItem Item 2",
  }  ............

]
```

And here are the Serializer, the Model and the view.

The Models:

```
class MainItem(models.Model):
   id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=50) 

class SubItem(models.Model):
  """Equates to parent items"""
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True) 
  main_item = models.ForeignKey(MainItem, null=False)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=50) 


 class Main(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  href = models.CharField(max_length=250)
  sub_items = models.ManyToManyField(SubItem)
```

The Serializer:

```
class SubItemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SubItem
        fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

The View:

```
class ItemsView(APIView):
      def get(self, request):

      items = SubItems.objects.select_related('main_item').all()
      issue_ser = SubItemSerializer(issues, many=True)

      return Response(issue_ser.data)
```

Comment: Can you show your code? Models, view and serializers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should rewrite your code to make it based on `MainItem` instead of `SubItem`.

Note you can get all related subitems by using MainItem `subitem_set` attribute. `<modelname>_set` is default reverse related name for many-to-one relation in Django.

So try something like this:

```
class MainItemSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MainItem
        fields = ('id', 'description', 'subitem_set')
        depth = 1

class ItemsView(APIView):
      def get(self, request):
          items = MainItem.objects.prefetch_related('subitem_set').all()
          issue_ser = MainItemSerializer(issues, many=True)

          return Response(issue_ser.data)
```

Comment: That worked absolutely perfect - thank you very much, and also your explanation makes it clear why it works.